# Remove class of a label when the corresponding input field has is filled in

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove the class `"visuallyhidden"` on labels of the text fields that have been filled in. So when I start typing something in an input field, I want the class `"visuallyhidden"` cleared so the label appears above the input field. However, when I erase the text from that input field, I want the class `"visuallyhidden"` to be added back to the corresponding label.

```
<label for="firstname" class="visuallyhidden">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>

<label for="lastname"  class="visuallyhidden">Last Name</label> 
<input type="text" id="lastname"  placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

My failed attempt at jQuery, which somewhat works, but affects all labels

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    $('label').addClass('visuallyhidden');
});
$('input').blur(function() {
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $('label').removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: I want ice cream.  However, this is not a "gimme the codez" site.  You are expected to show us your failed attempt at this, then we help you fix it.  Have you tried writing any jQuery at all?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sparky You've chosen the wrong duplicate. That question asks how to toggle class on focus and blur, this questions asks how to do so while typing. Also, it asks how to add class to the input itself, while this asks how to toggle class on near by label.  Both are way different. Plus, the answers for it are terrible...

Comment: @TJ, Since no jQuery code is shown in this question, I could argue that the duplicate generically shows how to toggle class on _any_ jQuery event.  Maybe you could find a better one to use as the duplicate.

Comment: @Sparky that doesn't answer how to do so in the nearby label. If you're closing something, please use proper reason. *"Add class on input (and remove if value hasn't changed)"* doesn't answer *"Remove class of a label when the corresponding input field has is filled in"*

Comment: @TJ, now you're repeating yourself and we have a difference of opinion.  You may have a stronger argument had this question been written properly in the first place.  I don't even see one single bit of jQuery here.

Comment: @Sparky That is my point. Then close it sighting the proper reason.  Tell the OP how he can improve the question, Pointing to a somewhat related typo question with weird answers isn't the brightest way for welcoming a new user.

Comment: @TJ, improper spelling ("sighting => citing") in your comment while insulting me isn't the brightest way either.

Comment: @Sparky When/where did I insult you..? BTW thanks for the spelling correction.

Comment: @TJ, we have a simple disagreement of opinion on the validity of the duplicate question and you say it's not "the brightest way". Saying "not bright" could be considered insulting. Additionally, arguing about it now is a moot point as I have no power to re-open this question.  Again, keep in mind that this question is about jQuery but contains no jQuery code whatsoever.  With that low starting point, almost any question showing the usage of jQuery event handlers would have relevance here.

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged as a duplicate, as this has nothing to do with an on click state of an input field. Anyhow, I added my failed attempt at jQuery, hopefully someone will be able to help out. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Since the OP has edited the question with the relevant code, I voted to re-open.  Apparently, my vote to re-open has more power than I thought as the question is now open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method as follows:

```js
$(":input").on("keyup", function() {
  $(this).prev("label").toggleClass("visuallyhidden", (this.value==""))
});
```

```css
.visuallyhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="firstname" class="visuallyhidden">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />

<label for="lastname" class="visuallyhidden">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Comment: Thanks T J, this works even better! I can erase everything in the input field, and even though it is still in focus, the label disappears. That's exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To target the specific `label`, you simply need to [traverse the DOM with jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)...

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    $(this).prev('label').addClass('visuallyhidden');
});
$('input').blur(function() {
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).prev('label').removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }
});
```

See: [jQuery `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

`$(this).prev('label')` grabs the immediate preceding sibling of `$(this)` that matches the `'label'` selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Everything works now as it should.

Comment: @SimonS., you're welcome.  Please, in the future, include all relevant code/info within the OP as your edit made all the difference here.